# How to get a value from view to Controller via Formcollection MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, detailsview

Im working on MVC2 ASP project.
The problem i got is that my cotroller not catch the value that coming from the view. 
I use Formcollection to catch the value from Textbox in my view,
 but when i run it, Collection shows Null all the time

here my controller

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Insert(FormCollection collection)
    {

        ProductionOrderItem item = new ProductionOrderItem();

        item.ProductionOrderNo =collection["DetailsView1$txtName"];
        item.ProductionOrderNo = collection["DetailsView1$TexMainOrder"];
        item.OrderDate = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month,DateTime.Now.Day);

}
```

here my ASPX page

```
<asp:DetailsView ID="DetailsView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateRows="False" 
         ClientIDMode="Static" DefaultMode="Insert" Height="50px" Width="125px" 
    EnableViewState="False">
        <Fields>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ProductionOrderNo">
                <InsertItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtName" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>
                </InsertItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="MainOrder">
                <InsertItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TexMainOrder" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>
                </InsertItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: You shouldn't be using server controls if this is MVC. Have you checked the generated names in the html for the textboxes are what you expect them to be?

Comment: dont understand what u realy mean,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed it.
i should give the full path where to catch data from,

so insted of

```
item.ProductionOrderNo =collection["textProductionOrderNo"];
```

i wrote

```
 item.ProductionOrderNo = collection["ctl00$MainContent$DetailsView1$textProductionOrderNo"];
```

Comment: This was what I suggested you do. You should mark this as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think it a good idea to have aspx textbox controls in your view I would rather use a regulat html textbox

```
<InsertItemTemplate>
                 <input type="txtName" id="txtName" name="fname">
                </InsertItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="MainOrder">
                <InsertItemTemplate>
               <input type="TexMainOrder" id="TexMainOrder" name="fname">
                </InsertItemTemplate>


    item.ProductionOrderNo =collection["txtName"];
    item.ProductionOrderNo = collection["TexMainOrder"];
```

even if you decide to use it you should add name and make it client id mode static

```
  <asp:TextBox ID="txtName" name="txtName" clientIdMode="static" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>
 <asp:TextBox ID="TexMainOrder" name="TexMainOrder" ClientIdMode="static" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: Still takes null when i look at Locals

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me that if you want to use FormCollection you need a Form.  I don't see one in your markup.

Comment: all the Detailsview is placed inside the  <form> tages

Comment: Is the FormCollection null?  Or the items you tried to pull from it?  In other words, are you looking at 'item.ProductionOrderNo' and finding it null after assigning 'collection["DetailsView1$TexMainOrder"];' to it?  Or are you examining the collection directly?  If it is the first, try the second.  Could be things not named as you expect.

Comment: yea im lm looking on 'item.ProductionOrderNo' efter assigning the collection and it shows have null.

Comment: I would set up a for/next loop to examine all the items in the FormCollection closely, as it might redefine the problem for you.